# Find the rank of system of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying linear algebra on my own, I have these problems and I don't seem to understand what to do to solve them:

Find the rank of a system of vectors $a_1, a_2, \dotsc$ and the maximum linear independant subsystem of this system, where:

$$\begin{align}
a_1 &= (2, 1, -3), \\
a_2 &= (3, 1, -5), \\
a_3 &= (1, 0, -7), \\
a_4 &= (4, 2, -1), \\
a_5 &= (1, 0, -2).
\end{align}$$

**Answer:** $r = 3$; $a_1, a_2, a_5$.

Can you tell me how this type of problems are solved?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what are you stuck on? Do you know how rank is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. Do you know row reduction ?

Place the vectors as columns in a matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}2&3&1&4&1\\
1&1&0&2&0\\
-3&-5&-7&-1&-2\end{pmatrix}$$ now preform row reduction to 
echelon reduced form.

to get

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&1&-1\\
0&1&0&1&1\\
0&0&1&-1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Now what has happened here is that the columns still represent the same vectors but expressed in a different basis.

Now we can read off any thing we want to know. Look at the first three columns in the reduced matrix, they are clearly linearly independent. Thus the rank is $3$ and $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are a maximal set.  Look at the fifth column, it is the second minus the first as you easily see from the reduced matrix, the same relation holds for the original vectors $a_5=-a_1+a_2$.